# Importing variable from another file creates an error

Tags: python, variables, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I'm using Python's Jupyter Notebooks, and have been trying to import a variable called *thresh_mean* from another file that's in the same folder.

```
import scipy.io as sio
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from firstsound import thresh_mean #this line
```

However, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-1ee7c2613f81> in <module>
      4 import pandas as pd
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 6 import firstsound

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firstsound'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can go about importing that variable?

Comment: Where is `firstsound` installed? The problem is broader than trying to import a name from the module; the module itself can't be created.

Comment: I have a folder on my desktop. Within that folder there's a jupyter notebook called firstsound.ipynb and within the same folder is the file I'm writing. I'm trying to summon a variable from within firstsound.pynb into the current notebook.

Comment: I don't use Jupyter myself; does it recognize `.pynb` files as valid modules? Python itself does not.

Comment: The extension for Jupyter notebooks is `.ipynb` and they cannot be imported the way Python can.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to pass a variable, you want to execute a command using `%store` somewhere in the source notebook after you define it, and then read it in to your other notebook by adding the `-r` option after `%store` to indicate read. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41981233/8508004) and #9 [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/jupyter-notebook-tips-tricks-shortcuts/).

```py
#next line run in source notebook
%store thresh_mean

#next line run in notebook trying to read the serialized variable
%store -r thresh_mean
```

(You may want to look into using [pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) to serialize and pass variables if you are going to be using them and passing them outside of your own Jupyter environment.)

If it was a function you can use [import-ipynb](https://pypi.org/project/import-ipynb/). There's also [nbimporter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50614132/8508004).