# How do I fix the Attribute Error that I get when trying to import a function from another .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to `print` the Intersection of Union (IoU) value of images when running `inspect_model.ipynb` from [this github repo](https://github.com/karolmajek/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/README.md). The function is in another python file (`model.py`). I've followed the steps in the answer from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576404/importing-functions-from-another-jupyter-notebook/50614132) but I'm getting the error message shown below.

Directory tree of the 2 files are :

```
/Mask_RCNN-master (working directory)

               / model.py
               / inspect_model.ipynb
```

Importing `nbimporter` and the file(`model.py`) containing the function

```
import nbimporter
import model
```

The code of the function that I want to call :

```
#to print IoU of image
class Accuracy():
    def __init__(self):
        print("IoU: ",iou)
```

The code I used to call the function in the notebook that I'm running :

```
new = model.Accuracy()
```

Error Message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-383458c9727b> in <module>()
     20 print("mAP @ IoU=50: ", np.mean(APs))
     21 
---> 22 new = model.Accuracy()

AttributeError: 'MaskRCNN' object has no attribute 'Accuracy'
```

Comment: Importing .py files into .ipynb files requires a few extra steps. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303402/cannot-import-py-file-to-ipython-notebook) might help.

Comment: The `model.py` file in that repo doesn't have a class named `Accuracy`. That word only appears once, in a comment, on [line 285](https://github.com/karolmajek/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/model.py#L285).

Comment: it looks like `model` is no module but rather was created with `model = MaskRCNN(...)` and now it can't find `Accuracy` in this `MaskRCNN`

Comment: @MattDMo Yupe it doesn't. I've added that class into `model.py` in order to run `print("IoU: ", iou)`. Then, I'd like to call it in the `inspect_model.ipynb` notebook

Comment: @furas So, the solution to that would be to run `from model import Accuracy` ? As pointed out by Justin Iven Muller in the Answer below.

Comment: @lpd11 Following the steps in the link that you provided with would import the entire .py file and run it right ? Instead of just a particular function in that file. Pls do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it can means that somewhere in current code you defined `model = ...` and this removed imported module and now you can't acces code from module `model` and you would have to remove or rename `model = ...`. And `from model import Accuracy` can't change it.

Comment: problem is also that in [model.py](https://github.com/karolmajek/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/model.py) (from repo) there is no `class Accuracy`. Where did you get this `class Accuracy` ?

Comment: I checked `inspect_model.ipynb` and there is `model = modellib.MaskRCNN(...)` and now `model` is not module but object `MaskRCNN` which doesn't have method `Accuracy()` - as you get in error message. Besides it imports mdoule as `import model as modellib` so you should use `modellib.Accurancy()`. But if you use only `import model` and later do `model = model.MaskRCNN(...)` then now you can't access module because it was replaced by `model = ...`

Answer (score -1):

Import:
`from model import Accuracy`

...and classes usually don't have brackets behind itself:

```
class Accuracy:
    def __init__(self):
        print("IoU: ",iou)
```

Comment: I tried it...I'm still getting `AttributeError: 'MaskRCNN' object has no attribute 'Accuracy'`